# How do I use jQuery timeago to live update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

I have a value `011-04-29T14:55:33.000Z` this value gets push into a jQuery template. I used [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to convert the date to elapsed time but after being written to the template it has no way of updating as more time passes.

How would I implement something that would automatically update?

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle.net and provide a little more info on what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you start with this (from the [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) homepage):

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

Now, the timeago plugin will change the title as it rewrites things. All you need to do is keep track of the timestamp elsewhere, put it back in the `title` attribute, and rerun the plugin. Something like this:

```
<abbr
    class="timeago"
    title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z"
    data-ts="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z"
>July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

Will become this:

```
<abbr
    class="timeago"
    title="July 17, 2008"
    data-ts="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z"
>2 years ago</abbr>
```

And when you want to update it, just put `data-ts` back in `title` and rerun the plugin:

```
$('.timeago').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('title', $this.data('ts'));
}).timeago();
```

If you're using an older jQuery, you might need to use `$this.attr('data-ts')` in place of `$this.data('ts')`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP was asking about, but I had to use  `$('.timeago').timeago('update', "2008-07-17T09:24:17Z");` to change the time it was using to calculate the time-ago in words.

Comment: @Nolan: Has the interface changed in the past two years? I think timeago was use the `title` attribute to get the raw timestamp and then overwriting it with the element's content, hence the `data-ts` attribute to keep an untouched version of the timestamp for refreshing. I'm sort of guessing here, 2011-04-30 was a long time ago :)

Comment: Yep, that's how it currently works, as far as I can tell. But setting the `title` *after* initializing timeago on the element doesn't change the reference time. I believe it just changes what's displayed in the tooltip, which makes sense: the title contains the tooltip text, and timeago stores the original datetime in `element.data('timeago')`. To get timeago to change the reference datetime, you can use the `'update'` function with the new datetime.

Comment: Timeago will automatically update the displayed text (the time ago, in words) for you. Is that new? Is that what the OP was trying to achieve? If so, 2011-04-30 was indeed 'a long time ago'...

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above with no luck.and i found this. might be helpful.

https://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/

Here `<span data-livestamp="your time goes here..."></span>` is enough.

Don't forget to add `jquery.js` and `moment.js` before `livestamp.js`

Comment: Thanks brother. Its works. Just dont forget livestamp.js

Comment: glad it helps brother @tigin